# Blender Python: How to test for "selectable" objects in viewport?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, select

Is there a way to check if objects are selectable in Blender Python?

The code below checks if an object is visible, but is there also something to check if an object is also selectable in viewport?

Example for checking if visible:

```
if obj.visible_get():
    # Do something...
```

The reason is: If you set off the "Object Types Selectibility" for Meshes, then they can still be selected using python or in the outliner. See my shot, which area I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution for my situation:

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.visible_get() and bpy.context.space_data.show_object_select_mesh == False:
        # Do something...
```

I forgot, I can use the Info window in Blender to see the most command codes, that were recently used by the user.

Comment: FWIW `if obj.visible_get() and not bpy.context.space_data.show_object_select_mesh` is [arguably more pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257554/difference-between-if-not-and-if-false). You can also consider [bpy.context.selectable_objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selectable_objects) so you don't miss out on unselectable objects in the outliner

Answer (score 4):

You can use the property `hide_select` to set an object's selectability:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
obj.hide_select = True # makes the cube not selectable
```

Then you can use it to check if it is selectable:

```
if obj.hide_select:
   print("object", obj, "is not selectable")
```

Comment: Interesting side note from playing around with your answer and mine: it's possible to disable an object's selectability when `show_object_select_mesh = True` but it's _not_ possible to enable an object's selectability when `show_object_select_mesh = False`. Hence a rigid check for selectability would need to be `if not obj.hide_select and show_object_select_mesh: ...`

Comment: @taiyo ah nice, this will all be useful information then for the community!

Answer (score 3):

You can query the *Object Types Visibility* dialog, for example for the `MESH` type:

```
def is_mesh_type_selectable():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            return area.spaces[0].show_object_select_mesh
        
    raise Exception('No 3D Viewport found.')
```

For the other object types, have a look in the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_object_select_mesh), they are all starting with `show_object_select...`.

Comment: In addition one can also use [bpy.context.selectable_objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selectable_objects) which accounts for object visibility and selectability (the outliner settings) - but not viewport overrides for visibility and selectability